# Way to plot single pixels on imshow-plot

Tags: python, plot, pixel, imshow

Let's assume I have in imshow like the following:

```
b = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,1,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(b)
```

[image]

Is there a way to plot pixels given by the 1s in the following array in any wanted colour (f.e. black)?

```
a = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,0,0,0,1,1],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

My idea was to plot a second imshow on the first with transparency, but this obviously doesn't work, because it also changes the sourrounding pixels.

You may have to get the indexes of the 1s with enumerate and then have to plot the pixels individually. But I haven't found a way, to draw full pixels on imshows. I think you can draw plots and points on imshows, but no full pixels. Am I right or am I missing something?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
liste = []
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(a):
        if value==1:
            liste.append(index)

for index in liste:
    index2 = (tuple(reversed((np.subtract(index, 0.5)))))
    rect = plt.Rectangle(index2, 1,1, color = 'red')
    ax.add_patch(rect)
```

Result:

[image]

Seems like a cheat solution to use rectangles. It's the best approach I could do.